# How to translate 'She got him bitten by the dog'?

Tags: translation

How to translate 'She got him bitten by the dog'?

Can I translate it as:
彼女は彼に犬に噛まれさせた？

Also, how should I translate 'She got him bitten on the hand by the dog'?

Can I translate it as:
彼女は彼に犬に手を噛まれさせた？

Answer (score 2):

I am a native speaker of Japanese but not of English. So my English may not be natural but I hope to be helpful.

If you translate directly, it would be 彼女は彼が犬に噛まれるようにした。
In this sentence 彼女(=she) is the subject and ようにした(=made) is verb.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I realize 〜させ isn't the only way to translate 'make'. 〜ようにする can serve more complicated situations. I would also like to ask, does this sentence make sense at all: 彼女は彼に犬に噛まれさせた? Is it possible to make a sentence with 噛まれさせた? (I mean any sentence.)

Comment: My pleasure! 噛まれされた is not grammatically correct because れ cannot connect with された. As another example, 騙された is correct but 騙されさせた is incorrect.

Comment: そうですか、分かりました＾＿＾

Answer (score 1):

"She made him bitten by the dog" is meaning She is the reason why he got bitten by the dog.

So it would be 彼は彼女のせいで犬に噛まれた。

彼女のせい =  Because of her

Comment: Thank you so much! But what about a direct translation without reinterpreting the original sentence?

Comment: @JoH The original isn’t grammatical or meaningful, so you have to interpret it as something else to understand and translate it.